# Firebird lock and select unlocked fields

Tags: sql, firebird, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have a query

```
SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM FP_TASKS WITH LOCK
```

but I have multiple clients using a table, and I need for each selected client 10 rows that are not locked..
Is there any way to do something like below?

```
SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM FP_TASKS
 WHERE ROW NOT LOCKED
WITH LOCK
```

Comment: `SELECT FIRST 10 * FROM FP_TASKS ` - this mean "select any random 10 rows" - because you did not specify any order

Comment: Firebird is multi-version server, locking is not natural for it. I guess, you'd better re-think the mode of operation of your applications. If you really need it that much, you may add column into the table, connection ID that locked this row. Still it seems to be rather unnatural workflow for IB/FB

Comment: I believe the best way will be to identify the connection, as you said. My application has a subprocess that consumes this table, where our connected clients can allocate the workload to each other, so the client can select any row to process in any specific order.


Thank you!

Comment: then also see database-level triggers, if your client or its connection crashes, then server should release locks of that connection

Comment: i added a trigger on event "On disconnect" and perfectly worked :)  ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold a lock a row, then another `select .. with lock` in another transaction will either wait for the lock to be released or raise an exception (depending on the transaction configuration).

There is no way to ignore or skip locked rows when selecting. The [Firebird documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-with-lock) also explicitly says:

> WITH LOCK provides a limited explicit pessimistic locking capability
>   for cautious use in conditions where the affected row set is:
>
> a. extremely small (ideally, a singleton), and
>   b. precisely controlled by the application code.

Your query is neither 'extremely small' nor 'precisely controlled' by your application.

You should consider allocating a row using a short transaction that updates the row with some type of connection-specific claim, or maybe a single producer or resource manager that allocates rows to a specific client.